How to create Calculated Measure to find matching values between two tables in Excel Power Pivot
I have two tables (i.e. 1st is 'Sales' Table, 2nd is 'Territory' table) in my Power Pivot, and I have established relationships between the two using a 'territory' column.
The 'Sales' table contains Sales Orders data (i.e. Invoice id, date, territory, customer name, product, qty, rate, total, etc.).

The 'Cities' table contains Cities data such as territory, Area, Country.


QUESTION: How to write a DAX Calculated Measure in MS Excel Power Pivot to find total Distinct Count of territories that had no sale.
REASON: I want to know how many distinct territories in each month had no sale (meaning the territory(ies) which did not appear in the Sales data for any selected month) via Pivot Tables I have created in my dashboard.


pls provide some sample data and expected output

You can create a new DAX measure from Power Pivot, Measures, New Measure, for example:
=CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Territory'[Territory]),
    FILTER(
        'Territory',
        NOT (
            'Territory'[Territory] IN
            CALCULATETABLE(
                VALUES('Sales'[Territory]),
                'Sales'[Date] >= DATE(2024, 1, 1),  -- Start Date (Adjust manually)
                'Sales'[Date] <= DATE(2024, 3, 31)  -- End Date (Adjust manually)
            )
        )
    )
)

Create a new a Power Pivot and add whatever fields you need:


Hello Michael,
Thanks so much.
However, I dont want to manually specify the date range in the Measure definition.
I want to do that in the pivot table, after closing the Data Model.
So, what should instead follow after the " (NOT 'Territory'[Territory] IN " ...

@Bori - so just remove this part from the measure and drop the date field in the pivot.  If it's not working, post your code and we can try to help you. I don't understand what the problems seems to be now.
